# I need help creating a modern NavBar

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

Because of feedback I have removed this post because its topic was not very understandable. As this was relatively new, I did not get any answers so this post does not provide any real help.

Comment: Yo I just said don't RIP my reputation, and it seems as if you didn't even leave any comment to explain why you did it and what you want me to work on in my question...

Comment: SO is not a "I need code; give me it" service. You will need to include some code that you've already tried - existing code => answers. The Internet is **full** of tutorials online to create a navbar. What do you mean by "modern"? You need to give some specification of what your'e aiming for - your question is too broad because of this.

Comment: Ok thank you I will show some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a navigation bar like the one on the website you provided, then have you tried using a basic version of its navigation bar's code? Just using the Inspect tool you can see that the navigation bar consists of two lists. These lists have been styled to be horizontal and have extra padding around the text.

Before posting to Stack Overflow, please attempt to solve the problem you are asking about. As you can see from your down votes the community is not here to provide full solutions for a problem. Stack Overflow is here to provide you resources to solve a specific problem that you have encountered in your attempt at creating a solution. Please read the [Stack Overflow question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question.